# LoadData() in OnCreateView of Fragment in TabView called Twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-pageradapter

Once my application is Login I start `ActivityTwo`. In ActivityTwo I am immediately calling `TabView` `Fragment` which hold my three Tabs.This is code in ActivityTwo to call TabView Fragment

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("TARGET_FRAGMENT_ID", fragId);
        ChooseTab chooseTab = new ChooseTab();
        chooseTab.setArguments(bundle);
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, chooseTab, add);
        ft.commit();
        });
```

This is code for ChooseTab Fragment which is responsible for setting TabView

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_tab, container, false);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        int position=getArguments().getInt("TARGET_FRAGMENT_ID");
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

This is code for PagerAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private int mNumOfTabs;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Tab1();
                case 1:
                    return new Tab2();
                case 2:
                    return new Tab3();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
```

This is code for `Tab1` `onCreateView`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_status, container, false);
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        LoadData();
        });
        return v;
    }
```

But when I run the app and I print some Log when LoadData() is called it is seen loadData is called. How to resolve this ?